# HTML5 DocType not getting set

Tags: visualforce, html5, apexpage, doctype

Any idea why this is not generating an html5 doctype in my pages?

```
<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" 
  cache="false" contentType="text/html" sidebar="false" 
  standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
```

API version is set to 36.0. When I open the console in IE11, I get this warning message:

> HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "".

Also, when I view the page's source in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11, I do not see a `<!doctyle html>` tag included in the markup.

Comment: what is your vf page api version? It has to be above API version 28.0!

Comment: Can you share us your findings on how did you identify that page is not generating Html5 doctype?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a "custom" contentType appears to suppress the DOCTYPE. Do not add this attribute if you need the DOCTYPE.

```
<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" 
           showHeader="false" cache="false" sidebar="false"
           standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
```